# How do I properly use StreamWriter when making multiple POST requests

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, streamwriter

I have a program that posts multiple transactions to an API, on average about 40/50 transactions per day and the program runs once daily (as a job). I am getting an error ***'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter'*** when the flow tries to loop through the second record. Only the first transaction is being posted but when the loop attempts second record the program ***either crashes*** or throws error ***'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter'***.

Program.cs

```
  List<Root2> details = GetRemmitances();
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.myloan.co.za/api/v1/inbound/create");
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-api-key", Helpers.apikey.ToString());
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 300000;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            try
            {
                foreach (var tran in details)
                {
                    jsonRecord = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tran);
                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine(jsonRecord);
                streamWriter.Write(jsonRecord);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                        {
                            File.Create(filePath).Dispose();
                        }
                        using (stream = File.AppendText(filePath))
                        {
                        stream.WriteLine(result);
                        stream.Flush();
                        stream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                   
              
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ExceptionLogger.SendErrorToText(ex);
            }
          
        }
```

Having done some searching I have removed  `stream.Close();` and `streamWriter.Close();` but this doesnt help either as the program continues to crash without throwing an error. I know that the using block also closes the TextWriter by definition so I have taken out all the logic out of the for loop as below :

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);            
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        foreach (var tran in details)
        {
            jsonRecord = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tran);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonRecord);
            streamWriter.Write(jsonRecord);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            sw.WriteLine(result);
            sw.Flush();
        } 
       sw.Close();
       streamWriter.Close();
```

This time I am getting error **"400 Bad Request"** despite that I am not posting a duplicate record (the upstream API doesnt accept duplicates and throws 400 Bad Request for such).

I am not sure if the refactor is entirely correct or how to change the original implementation if need be.

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't written anything to the request stream

Comment: @Crowcoder I thought so as much .. Where should I put the those lines

Comment: Check out [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getrequeststream?view=net-6.0)